# Drawn pixel using pencil on canvas is not centred

Tags: javascript, vue.js, p5.js

I am drawing pixels using a pencil on canvas using p5.js.
The issue is that when the pencil size is 1 or smaller in that scenario, its position is not centered.
It's coming left right not centered.

**I've noticed an interesting observation in our code. It appears that when the mouse's x and y positions are close to .5, the drawn pixel appears centered; however, in other instances, the pixel seems to be slightly off-center. To tackle this, I'm thinking of refining our rendering logic. I'll make sure to set the pixel density to 1 to prevent any automatic scaling issues. Additionally, I might experiment with adjusting the pixel position by incorporating a correction factor, perhaps subtracting 0.5 from both the x and y coordinates. It's crucial to scrutinize any transformations or scaling operations in our code that could be influencing the exact placement of pixels.**

> I've noticed that the P5.image.set method doesn't seem to accept
> floating-point numbers; it rounds to the nearest integer. Has anyone
> found a workaround for this issue, or am I missing something in the
> documentation?

[Here](https://github.com/Akash1994Gowda/Vue---P5.Js-Canvas/blob/main/src/App.vue) is the code.
[Here](https://peppy-sunshine-5eff6d.netlify.app/) is the deployed application.

Steps to generate the issue:-

1. open the link
2. zoom(mouspress+wheel)
3. select pencil
4. mouse press on canvas

Thanks in advance.
If any query comments I will add more clarity.

Below is the code of mousepressed method in the for loop we are setting pixel values

```
mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY) {
      if (this.menuSelection === 'drawPencil') {
        this.mapImage.loadPixels()
        let size = 1
        let y = mouseY
        for (let i = mouseX - size / 2; i < mouseX + size / 2; i++) {
          for (let j = y - size / 2; j < y + size / 2; j++) {
            this.mapImage.set(i, j, this.p5.color(255))
            //console.log('i,j', i, j)
          }
        }
        this.mapImage.updatePixels()
        return
      }
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please tell me what does this do? ```for (let i = mouseX - size / 2; i < mouseX + size / 2; i++) {
          for (let j = y - size / 2; j < y + size / 2; j++) {
            this.mapImage.set(i, j, this.p5.color(255))
            console.log('i,j', i, j)
          }
        }```

Comment: With and without it `clientX` and `clientY` is same.

Comment: @KamranAllana  using this for loop I am setting pixel value to the mapImage variable for drawing pixels.

Comment: There is different operation on different screens, as I supposed initially about the marker as it was pointing upper side 20-30 pixels above marker center so I fixed that first.

Comment: @KamranAllana I have added the screenshot please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said:

> I've noticed that the P5.image.set method doesn't seem to accept floating-point numbers; **it rounds to the nearest integer.** Has anyone found a workaround for this issue, or am I missing something in the documentation?

Because of this you need to floor the values always,

So 0.9 must be set to 0 even though it is closer to 1.
so you should floor any float number before passing it to P5.image.set method.

[image]

For example: the image here scaled up to fit the screen, so in this image if you click on the green area you will select pixel A instead of B (this caused by rounding the float values) if you floor the values yourself it will select B

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is I want a drawn pixel at the exact position of the mouse.

Comment: @NileshMishra Sorry, I've got it backward. I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks! I think this approach should work. let me check once.

Answer (score 2):

All it happening is that, when clicking on draw user need to scroll and it get position on mouse position on screen not on canvas.

```
p5.mousePressed = () => {
        ;(this.x_value = p5.mouseX), (this.y_value = p5.mouseY)
        // if (this.firstTime) {
        this.mx = p5.mouseX
        this.my = p5.mouseY
        this.firstTime = false
        // }

        this.mousePressedFlag = true
        this.mousePressed(p5.mouseX, p5.mouseY)
      }
```

```
mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY) {
      if (this.menuSelection === 'drawPencil') {
        
        this.mapImage.set(mouseX, mouseY, this.p5.color(255))
        this.mapImage.updatePixels()
        return
      }
    },
```

Update these functions and check it will work as you want.

## Updated

I've tried with little different approach, it's working fine as you wanted but need fixation as I've rewrite some of the code.

```
import p5 from 'p5'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imageLoad: null,
      menuSelection: null,
      mapImage: null,
      x_value: 0,
      y_value: 0,
      mousePressedFlag: false,
      sf: 1,
      mx: 0,
      my: 0,
      zoom: 1,
      loadImageWidth: 1500,
      loadImageHeight: 700,
      arrZoomScale: [
        0.1, 0.25, 0.33, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 6, 7, 8,
        10, 12
      ],
      viewPort: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
      },
      points: [],
      firstTime: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let p5Handler = (p5) => {
      p5.preload= () => {
        this.imageLoad = p5.loadImage('image.png', (img) => {
          p5.resizeCanvas(img.width, img.height)
        })
      }
      p5.setup = () => {
        const canvas = p5.createCanvas(1500, 700)
        canvas.parent(this.$refs.p5Container)
        p5.imageMode(p5.CENTER)
        p5.noStroke()
      }
      p5.draw = () => {
        this.draw(p5)
      }
      p5.mouseClicked = (event) => {
        ;(this.x_value = event.clientX), (this.y_value = event.clientY)
        // if (this.firstTime) {
        this.mx = (event.clientX  - p5.width / 2) / this.zoom
        this.my = (event.clientY  - p5.height / 2) / this.zoom
        this.firstTime = false
        // }

        this.mousePressedFlag = true
        this.mousePressed(event.clientX, event.clientY)
      }

      p5.mouseWheel = (event) => {
        this.mouseWheel(event)
      }
    }
    let P5 = p5
    this.p5 = new P5(p5Handler)
  },
  methods: {
    draw(p5) {
      p5.background(255);
      p5.translate(p5.width / 2, p5.height / 2);
      p5.scale(this.zoom);
      p5.image(this.imageLoad, 0, 0);

      this.points.forEach(({ x, y, size }) => {
        p5.fill(255, 255, 255)
        p5.rect(x, y, size)
      })

      if (this.menuSelection === 'drawPencil') {
        p5.translate(this.mx, this.my)
        p5.translate(-this.mx, -this.my)
        p5.translate()

        p5.cursor(p5.CROSS)
        p5.strokeWeight(0.3 / this.zoom)
        p5.noFill()
        p5.stroke(69, 69, 69)
        p5.rect((p5.mouseX - p5.width / 2) / this.zoom, (p5.mouseY - p5.height / 2) / this.zoom, 1)
      }
    },
    mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY) {
      const cMouseX = (mouseX - this.p5.width / 2) / this.zoom
      const cMouseY = (mouseY - this.p5.height / 2) / this.zoom
      this.points.push({ x: cMouseX, y: cMouseY, size: 1 })
    },
    mouseWheel(event) {
      /* const delta = this.p5.constrain(event.deltaY * 0.01, -0.2, 0.2)
      this.zoom += delta
      this.zoom = this.p5.constrain(this.zoom, 0.1, 5) */

      if (this.mousePressedFlag) {
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
          this.zoomOut()
        } else {
          this.zoomIn()
        }
      }
    },
    zoomIn() {
      for (let zoom of this.arrZoomScale) {
        if (zoom > this.zoom) {
          this.setZoom(zoom, 'zoomIn')
          break
        }
      }
    },
    zoomOut() {
      // Sort the array of zoom scales in ascending order
      this.arrZoomScale.sort((a, b) => a - b);

      // Find the index of the zoom level in the array that is just smaller than the current zoom
      const index = this.arrZoomScale.findIndex(scale => scale >= this.zoom) - 1;

      if (index >= 0) {
        const newZoom = this.arrZoomScale[index];
        console.log(newZoom)
        this.setZoom(newZoom, 'zoomOut');
      }
    },
    setZoom(newZoom, val) {
      if (val === 'zoomIn') {
        this.sf = newZoom
      } else if (val === 'zoomOut') {
        this.sf = newZoom
      }
      this.zoom = newZoom
    },
  }
}
```

links helped alot:

- https://editor.p5js.org/J-Cake/sketches/1r1wmWO60
- https://editor.p5js.org/heothesennoc/sketches/JhGOH9VfC
- https://editor.p5js.org/mimimimimi/sketches/SOkckqY_r

Comment: Thanks for the answer!     But it is not working .

Comment: There was `console.log(this.canvas)` which occurs error as I put on my local to test. I've updated the answer, kindly do try and let me know

Comment: https://deploy-preview-1--peppy-sunshine-5eff6d.netlify.app/ you can check it here!

Comment: This is not working I already tried these things. Can you have some other approach then let me know? In Your deployed app pixel is also not centered.

Comment: Well, on this deployed app pixel draw on center point of marker. I didn't get why it's not on your side. I'll try other approach too till then good luck dear

Comment: Can we chat to resolve this, might I've understand differently?

Comment: I think you are checking without zooming. first zoom then try to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256284/discussion-between-nilesh-mishra-and-kamran-allana).

Comment: Thank you for your response. While I appreciate your input, I'm still facing the same issue. Could you please make a change in my code only?

Comment: Sure, give me a while.
I figured out the issue that `draw` function is always on loop so we have to initialize background on `setup`, when zoom in or zoom out works it's better to use `scale()` and then all the dots can be push to array so on draw they just call for placement on the image.

Comment: I'm sharing you the link so you can check first so I'll update in your code as well. https://deploy-preview-1--peppy-sunshine-5eff6d.netlify.app/

Comment: Now there is an issue on zoom out, I'm trying to solve it. You can visit the link above so it would help me to correct on the way.

Comment: I've noticed that the P5.image.set method doesn't seem to accept floating-point numbers; it rounds to the nearest integer. Has anyone found a workaround for this issue, or am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Might be, checked that it accepts `Number` but I guess it accepts float too. https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image/set

Comment: Bro, I have already gone through the documentation. you are not getting my question.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that it rounds to nearest integer but if doesn't so It wouldn't be accurate creating eclipse by clicking on zoomed in and out canvas. 
Reference: https://editor.p5js.org/heothesennoc/sketches/JhGOH9VfC

Comment: @NileshMishra check now and let me know https://deploy-preview-1--peppy-sunshine-5eff6d.netlify.app/

Comment: There is just a single issue that is when I zoom out pixel push at little far but when I zoom in it works fine. Updated on your code, updating the answer as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256327/discussion-between-kamran-allana-and-nilesh-mishra).

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code

```
p5.mouseMoved = (event) => {
   this.mouseMoved(event)
}
```

after

```
p5.mouseWheel = (event) => {
   this.mouseWheel(event)
}
```

Then modify methods code block as follows,

```
methods: {
    draw(p5) {
      let ctx = p5;
      if (this.mousePressedFlag) {
        p5.translate(this.mx, this.my);
        p5.scale(this.sf);
        p5.translate(-this.mx, -this.my);
      }

      this.drawMapImage(ctx); // ctx as arg
      if (this.menuSelection === 'drawPencil') {
        this.p5.cursor(this.p5.CROSS);
        p5.strokeWeight(0.3 / this.zoom);
        p5.noFill();
        p5.stroke(69, 69, 69);
        p5.rect(p5.mouseX - 0.5, p5.mouseY - 0.5, 1, 1); // Adjusted pixel position
      }
    },
    mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY) {
      if (this.menuSelection === 'drawPencil') {
        this.mapImage.loadPixels();
        let size = 1;
        let y = mouseY;
        for (let i = mouseX - size / 2; i < mouseX + size / 2; i++) {
          for (let j = y - size / 2; j < y + size / 2; j++) {
            this.mapImage.set(Math.floor(i), Math.floor(j), this.p5.color(255)); // Use Math.floor to ensure integer coordinates
          }
        }
        this.mapImage.updatePixels();
        return;
      }
    },
    mouseMoved() {
      if (this.mousePressedFlag) {
        this.setZoomCenter(this.p5.mouseX, this.p5.mouseY);
      }
    },
    mouseWheel(event) {
      if (this.mousePressedFlag) {
        let zoomChange = event.deltaY > 0 ? -0.1 : 0.1; // Adjust the zoom factor as needed
        this.setZoom(this.zoom + zoomChange);
        this.setZoomCenter(this.p5.mouseX, this.p5.mouseY);
      }
    },
    drawMapImage(p5) {
      let ctx = this.mapImage.drawingContext
      ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
      this.imageContext = ctx

      ctx = p5.canvas.getContext('2d')
      ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
      this.htmlContext = ctx

      p5.push()

      p5.image(
        this.mapImage,
        0,
        0,
        this.viewPort.width / this.zoom,
        this.viewPort.height / this.zoom
      )
      p5.pop()
    },
    zoomIn() {
      for (let zoom of this.arrZoomScale) {
        if (zoom > this.zoom) {
          this.setZoom(zoom, 'zoomIn')
          break
        }
      }
    },
    zoomOut() {
      for (let i = this.arrZoomScale.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let zoom = this.arrZoomScale[i]
        if (zoom < this.zoom) {
          this.setZoom(zoom, 'zoomOut')
          break
        }
      }
    },
    setZoom(newZoom) {
      this.sf = newZoom;
      this.zoom = newZoom;
      this.recalViewPort();
    },
    setZoomCenter(x, y) {
      this.mx = x;
      this.my = y;
    },
    recalViewPort() {
      this.viewPort.width = this.zoom * this.loadImageWidth
      this.viewPort.height = this.zoom * this.loadImageHeight
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! If I send the floor value, the pixel drawn will deviate from the mouse position.